# Custom message footer view with additional content

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, messagekit

I spent a couple of days already googling for docs, examples or like this, but I can't find answer for my question.

I need to show some additional content for each message, under the text area, like on this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFVMe.png) (I can't embed it into the post).

So, what I tried to do is to register a supplementary view in `messagesCollectionView`:

```
let nibName = String(describing: MessageBottomView.self)
let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: nil)
self.messagesCollectionView.register(
    nib,
    forSupplementaryViewOfKind: nibName, 
    withReuseIdentifier: nibName
)
```

and then to dequeue it in `MessagesDisplayDelegate`:

```
func messageFooterView(for indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageReusableView {
    let nibName = String(describing: MessageBottomView.self)

    return messagesCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
        ofKind: nibName, 
        withReuseIdentifier: nibName, 
        for: indexPath
    ) as! MessageBottomView
}
```

But I don't see my view under messages.

So my question is why? And which way I have to be looking for in case of I'm doing something wrong.

Unfortunately the documentation of `MessageKit` is not so informative, as it might be, and there is no similar question, or I can't find them at least, possibly because I even don't know which keywords I should search for.

Comment: Is your `messageFooterView` delegate method getting triggered?

Comment: @Miloš Perić Have you found what causing this issue? i'm also having the same issue. if you resolved it. please help me to figure out it.

Answer (score 1):

[Checkout this Link](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/issues/847) 
You are inserting the Xib to Message footerview,But not setting the size of the footerview.Please refer the above link to get more clarity about inserting Messageresusableviews.

```
  func footerViewSize(for section: Int, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 123, height: 123)
}
```